# AngularJS installation (official tutorial)

Tags: angularjs, npm-install, elementary-os

so I am trying to learn AngularJS , I am following the official turorial , when I run

```
sudo npm install
```

I get this answer

```
root@gaith-HP-15-Notebook-PC:/angular-phonecat# sudo npm install
npm WARN cannot run in wd angular-phonecat@0.0.0 bower install                                          
(wd=/angular-phonecat)
```

I am using elementary OS

Comment: Try `sudo bower install angular --allow-root`, elementary OS is from Unix family try http://protechvisit.blogspot.com/2016/11/angular-2-hello-world.html for setup angular  or clone https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/README.md